# Understanding FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, io, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

I writing a simple sample program, that should write a data to file and read in real time when there is some data. I write this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string file = "sample.txt";

            var thread = new Thread(() =>
                                    {
                                        var r = new Random();
                                        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {AutoFlush = true})
                                        {
                                            while (true)
                                            {
                                                Thread.Sleep(r.Next(100, 500));
                                                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
            thread.Start();

            using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
                                 {
                                     Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                                     Filter = file,
                                     NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 })
            {
                var mse = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
                watcher.Changed += (sender, eventArgs) => 
                    mse.Set();
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        mse.Wait();
                        ProcessData(sr.ReadToEnd());
                        mse.Reset();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private static void ProcessData(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that `watcher` works only when file is opened, but doesn't when it is populated with info (even with `AutoFlush` flag enabled on `StreamWriter`). Data is physically on the disk but watcher doesn't raise an event `File changed`.

I just want to avoid infinite loop and process data only when it is written.

Comment: do you close the writer?

Comment: @TaW you see the entire code, so answer is no. File is populating in `real time` and assume to be opened while PC is working. In fact I need behaviour `flush occured - event raised` while we cannot modify writer's code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't close them I think you should dispose of both the `FileStream` and the `StreamWriter` by putting each in a `using` clause:

```
string file = "sample.txt";
using (var fs =new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, 
                                    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs) {AutoFlush = true})
{
    ..
    ..
}
```

Before closing directly or by disposing, the file system will not be informed that the changes are done. Otherwise you would be flooded with changed events..

Comment: In this case I should dispose a stream for every line I write to fire an event. It's not very good. I need to know from another process if some data was appended in file. The only way I see is `while(true) if  (!stream.EndOfStream) ProcessData(stream.ReadToEnd())` that guarantee that actual data is readed. But infinite loop is not a very good approach, while we have events. But they doesn't work as expected.